# Using pointers to find positions of characters between unbalances parentheses

Tags: c++, pointers, parentheses

I am given a C++ programming problem: In a string I need to find wether or not there are balanced parentheses. If not, using pointers I should find position of the characters between unclosed parentheses (between second opening and nearest closing). 
The problem statement is a bit confusing, I know. I think it should work somehow like that:

Input #1:

```
((aba)aaab)
```

Output:

```
OK.
```

Input #2:

```
(aa(a)ab
```

Output:

```
Parentheses not balanced: between characters 1 and 6.
```

Code below solves part of problem with the closed parentheses check and also there is a structure to keep the address of the opening parenteses. I am not sure how exactly to use pointers for that purposes, some attempts did not give any result, so I need some help here.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<stack>

using namespace std;

struct br_data{
    char br_t;
    char *cptr;     //store the address of the opening parenthesis
};

int main (){
    string input;
    int addr;
    br_data br;
    getline(cin, input);

    stack<br_data> braces;
    char *a = input[0];  
    auto init_char = static_cast<void*>(&a); //store the address of the first character in the input string
    cout << static_cast<void*>(&a) << endl;  //gives the address in memory
    for(auto c: input) {
        if (c == '(') {
            br.br_t = c;
            br.cptr = &c;   //storing the address of the first parenhesis
            braces.push(br);
        } else if (c == ')' ) {
            if (braces.empty())
                cout << "This line does not contain unclosed parentheses\n";
            if (!braces.empty())
                braces.pop();
        }
    }
    if (!braces.empty()){
        //int addr = br.cptr;
        cout << "This line does not contain unclosed parentheses\n";
        //int pos = (&br.cptr) - (&a); //how to calculate the position??
        cout << "Position of the second opening parenthis is " << () << endl;
        //cout << "Position of the nearest closing parenthis is " << -how?? (static_cast<void*>(&br.cptr)) << endl;
    }
    if (braces.empty()){
        cout << "Parentheses are balanced in this line\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you have two pointers to the same array (or if one of them is one beyond the end of the array) then you can subtract them to get the distance in elements. Example: `char s[] = "foobar"; char* a = &s[1]; char* b = &s[4]; std::cout << "b - a = " << b - a << '\n';`

Comment: As for the code you show, `input[0]` is a *single `char`*. To get a pointer to it you should do `&input[0]`. Furthermore, `&a` is a pointer *to the pointer*, its type is `char**`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write

```
       br.cptr = &c;   //storing the address of the first parenhesis
```

you're actually storing the address of a local object of char type declared earlier:

```
auto c: input
```

By the moment you exit the loop it is officially dangling.

One simplest solution would be to actually consider string's characters, not their local copies:

```
for(auto &c: input) {
```

(and, even better, change auto into char for better clarity keeping source length the same). Then you can go on and see how your solution needs to be fixed further.

(A few extra free advice: input[0] is a rvalue reference of type char so it makes no sense to assign it to a variable of type `char *`, and what you try to do in that line is actually written as `char *a = input.c_str();` or `input.data()` or even `&input[0]`, pick the best option; and br.cptr is of type pointer-to-char already, so the character's position in a string would be calculated as `br.cptr - a`, you need to subtract the pointers themselves, not their addresses.)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(){
    char str[]="Hello Programming";
    char *ptr;
    char ch;
    char s;
    s='n';
    
    
   ptr=str;
   cout<<"To be found Character"<<endl;
   cin>>ch;
   
   while(*ptr++ != '\0')
   if(*ptr==ch)
   s='y';
   
   if (s=='y')
   cout<<"FOUND";
   
   else 
   cout<<"not found";``
   return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.